# Limit on S3 HttpConnection pool and Streaming timeout period

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

1. Is there any limit on maximum number of concurrent connections I can make to stream data in parallel from S3? I am using the java SDK. I have set the max connections in the ClientConfiguration to 200. But is there any hard limit imposed by the client or server?
2. From S3 documentation

   When you download an object, you get all of object's metadata and a stream    from which to read the contents. You should read the content of the stream as quickly as possible because the data is streamed directly from Amazon S3 and your network connection will remain open until you read all the data or close the input stream

What if the connection is open for a long time? I believe S3 closes the connection from server side after certain amount of time (which is quite low). Because I have experienced connection closed by server errors in past. But is there any timeout period which can be used to make sure the connection is not closed?